# How to use indirect reference to select a single cell or range in vba

Tags: vba, excel, reference, range, cell

I need simply a code for selecting a cell, however that cell to select changes. I have a cell in the workbook that will identify what cell it should be. Cell A1 contains the cell # that should be selected.

In this example cell A1 contains the word "P25", so I want the below code to reference A1 for the indirect cell ref to P25, thus select cell P25.

I tried both of these lines separately:

```
Sub IndirectCellSelect()

     Sheet.Range(INDIRECT(A1)).Select
     Range(INDIRECT(A1)).Select

End Sub
```

I get the error Sub or Function is not defined, when it gets to the word INDIRECT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A slight alteration to the posted code works:

```
Range([indirect("a1")]).Select
```

but I would advise to try either of these instead:

```
Sheet.Range(Sheet.Range("A1").Value).Select
Range(Range("A1")).Select
```

the first being more explicit and is recommended in production code.

Comment: Thanks! The first and third ones worked! I will go with the third one since you advise them instead.

Comment: The second formula needs adapting to the sheet you are using, this would be `Sheet1` for the first sheet of a new workbook. This is often recommended in practice as then the code will always work the same and won't depend on which sheet is currently active.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a different way, but if you want to use a native Excel worksheet function within your VBA code, you need to do this like so (note that I have also adjusted how you reference A1):

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Indirect(Sheets(1).Range("A1"))
```

**Edit**
Apologies - I hadn't test this. It seems that the Indirect function is not available in this context. Instead, try something like this:

```
Dim rng as Range
Set rng = sheets(1).Range("A1")

sheets(1).Range(rng.text).Select
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am not familiar with how to utilize a function properly. I tried a couple ways to no avail and just read the differences between when to use a function, but still couldn't implement it. I just get error "Object doesnt support this property or method" Also does Sheets(1) matter if the sheet name is different or is that simply 1 = active?

Comment: See my edits - this works for most functions but it appears that 'Indirect' is not supported in this way. makes sense as that is more confusing IMO anyway.

Comment: Ahh great, yeah that seems safer as I have ran into that issue in the past, ill make that one work! Any chance you have knowledge on this post? No one has responded and its been up for 1 month...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30764616/downloaded-new-versions-of-files-need-to-be-opened-and-saved-to-work-automatic-r

Answer (score 0):

```
Worksheets("list").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range(INDIRECT("I16" & "3" & ":" & "I16" & "5002")) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With Worksheets("list").Sort
        .SetRange Range("B2:K5002")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can clarify your answer by adding a more detailed explanation along with the code sample.