# Selecting Multiple Cells Using Variables in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

If I want to select multiple cells in Excel with VBA I do this:

```
range("A1:B4").Select
```

If my rows are the values of a variable, I don't know how to select those cells.

Any one know how to do that?

Comment: indirect (your cell) ?

Comment: You can also rely on this approach. For example: Dim CellFrom As String Dim CellTo As String CellFrom = "A1" and CellTo = "B4" you can do: range(CellFrom & ":" & CellTo).Select. You might also access the Columns/Rows via indices (which are 1-based, but not everything in VBA, which has nothing to do with VB.NET coupled with Excel, is 1-based by default -> I am clarifying this because I had a long discussion a while ago about this :)). There are quite a few alternatives. Perhaps you should take a look at some basic sample codes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31301086/1458030

Comment: That worked, thank you thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the examples for currently selected sheet:

```
Sub test()
    TopRow = 1
    BottomRow = 10
    LeftColumn = 3
    RightColumn = 9
    Range(Cells(TopRow, LeftColumn), Cells(BottomRow, RightColumn)).Select
End Sub
```

And for certain specified sheet:

```
Sub test()
    SheetName = "Test"
    TopRow = 1
    BottomRow = 10
    LeftColumn = 3
    RightColumn = 9
    With Sheets(SheetName)
        .Select
        .Range(.Cells(TopRow, LeftColumn), .Cells(BottomRow, RightColumn)).Select
    End With
End Sub
```